# How do I get a program that has to loop over 10000 times to run?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program in java that basically simulates a random walk by moving 1 x or y value for each step. Ex. starts at (0, 0), using Math.random, I can x++ or y-- which changes the x or y coordinate by one value. This walk terminates once the absolute value of both the x and y value added together gives me the number inputted (by command line argument). There are two command line integers, the first being the number just mentioned and the second being the trials, which is the number of times I have to simulate this walk.  By the end of this program, a step counter keeps track of how many steps were taken in each trial, and it is then averaged to give the average number of steps it took for each trial to add up to the number.

The problem I am having is that when I run my program, no error shows up or anything, it just doesn't run which gives me the idea that the runtime is just too long and there are too many iterations to go through. The input for the trials variable is going to be around 100000 to 1000000. I would appreciate any help or ideas on fixing this problem.

Here is my code for the program:

```
public class RandomWalkers {
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double trials = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        
        double avgSteps = 0;
        double totalSteps = 0;
        
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        
        int steps;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < trials; j++ ) {
            
            int trialDistance = 0;
        
        for(steps = 0; trialDistance != r; steps++) {
            double random = Math.random();
            
            if(random < 0.25) {
                x++;
            } else if((0.25 < random) && (random < 0.50)) {
                x--;
            } else if((0.50 < random) && (random < 0.75)) {
                y++;
            } else if((0.75 < random) && (random < 1.00)) {
                y--;
            } else {}
            
            totalSteps = totalSteps + steps;
            trialDistance = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y);
        
        }

        }
        
        avgSteps = totalSteps / trials;
        System.out.println("average number of steps = " + avgSteps);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: It is running, it just may take a very long time to finish.  Try running with a small number of trials first and you should see it finish. Repeat the run increasing the number of trials and it will take longer and longer to finish.

Comment: Because random numbers occur in a normal distribution, your "walker" will remain close to (0,0) for a long time.

Comment: The key why this is running practically "forever" is that you really simulate each and every step, and there will be a huge amount of steps necessary. Instead you could dive into the probabilities math and compute the results from the expected probability distributions (disclaimer: I don't know the formulas you'll need for this).

Answer (score 0):

ok so here an updated version.

```
public class RandomWalkers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int radius = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    walk(radius, trials);
    }

    public static void walk(int radius, int trials) {
    //not really a radius, but nvm

    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++) {
        
        //you need to reset the x and y for every trial!
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int steps = 0;
        
        while (Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) != radius) {

        double random = Math.random();

        if (random < 0.25) {
            x++;
        } else if (random < 0.50) {
            x--;
        } else if (random < 0.75) {
            y++;
        } else {
            y--;
        }

        steps++;
        }

        //take this out of the loop or increase only by one!
        totalSteps += steps;

    }

    double avgSteps = totalSteps / (double) trials;
    System.out.println("average number of steps = " + avgSteps);
    }

}
```

i moved everthing to another method (doesnt change anything) but what you can change:

- remove the first part of the else if's cause if the random *is* smaller than .25 it wont even trigger the else. You can also change the last one to a normal "else".
- take the "totalsteps = totalsteps + steps" out of the loop -> you dont want to add it with every step.
- i guess its better to handle the trials as an int and only cast it to a double for the calculation of the avg.
- you need to update the x,y and steps with every trial, else the second trial would be immediatly done with the result of the first

it should be fast enough to make 1mil trials or whatever, just be carefull with the "radius" its going to increase the time dramatically